# (illustrator) using blend tool to blend from a curve to hard angled shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo

Can i use the blend tool to create this type of flow from a curve to an edgier shape (shown on each leaf)?

[image]

When i try to do the blend this occurs to me
[image]

Comment: You could merely use a clipping mask on a blend to cut off edges at an angle you want.

Comment: In your updated example.. add 2 more anchors to the curved path (Object > Path > add Anchor Points). It's best to blend paths when they have an **equal** number of anchors, if you want smoother blends.

Comment: @Scott - looks like your two comments were in fact not only an answer, but the correct one per the OP...